# How to use a Mock inside of autowired bean

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

The following code is just an example. I use Spring Boot and Mockito

```
class MyTestClass{

 @Autowired
 MyController myController;

 @Test
 void testMethod(){
 Actor actor = myController.getActorOverHTTP();  <--- Staff inside this method must be mocked
 myController.someStaff(actor);
 }
}
```

The Problem is that inside of **getActorOverHTTP** I do something like

```
return httpClient.requestActor();
```

where httpClient is a @Service anotated bean.

I want to Mock my Class **"HttpClient"** I want return a dummy Actor when requestActor(); called. How I can do that with Mockito?

Comment: What is `HttpClient.requestActor`? A static field?

Comment: No this was just prototyping. I Updated my Question. httpClient is Spring Boot @Service